# c++ copy assignment operator classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a problem with the operator = in my class. This is the semplified code:

class:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Mat{

private:

int *m1;
int *m2;
unsigned rows;
unsigned cols;

void write(unsigned r_max, unsigned c_max){
    m1 = new int [r_max*c_max];
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < r_max*c_max; i++){
        m1[i] = i;
    }       
}

public:

Mat():
rows(1), cols(1){
    m1 = new int [1];
    m1[0] = 0;
    m2 = new int [1];
    m2[0] = 0;
}

Mat(unsigned r, unsigned c):
rows(r), cols(c){
    write(rows, cols);
    m2 = new int [rows*cols];
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++)
        m2[i] = 0;
}

Mat &operator=(const Mat &w){
    int *new_ptr1 = NULL;
    new_ptr1 = new int [w.rows*w.cols];
    int *new_ptr2 = NULL;
    new_ptr2 = new int [w.rows*w.cols];
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < w.rows*w.cols; i++){
        new_ptr1[i] = w.say_m1(i);
        new_ptr2[i] = w.say_m2(i);
    }
    delete[] w.m1;
    delete[] w.m2;
    m1 = new_ptr1;
    m2 = new_ptr2;
    rows = w.rows;
    cols = w.cols;
    return *this;
}

int say_m1(unsigned i) const{ return m1[i]; }

int say_m2(unsigned i) const{ return m2[i]; }

~Mat(){
    delete[] m1;
    delete[] m2;
}

};
```

Here is what I need to do in the main:

```
#include "Mat.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

Mat a;
Mat b(20, 20);
a = b;

return 0;

}
```

I think the problem is in the class where I overload the operator =
I don't know how to copy the right object data into the left object data, I'm not sure also if I delete correctly...

Comment: Look out for the [rule-of-three](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+rule-of-three)

Comment: You need to tell us what's going wrong.  Is it crashing?  Are you fearing a memory leak?

Comment: Compiled clean under g++.  What is the actual problem?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Or better still, the rule of zero. If you used `std::vector` rather than manually-juggled arrays, the class would automatically be assignable.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Usually the poor guys asking such questions aren't allowed to use `std::string` or other stuff they _'hadn't learned yet'_.

Comment: It doesn't compile with g++

Comment: @Wellen what's the error message from g++ then?

Comment: @Wellen:  Did you really intend to `#include "Mat.cpp"`?  CPP files are not usually `#include`ed

Comment: @Wellen:  I just said that it *did* compile under g++.  If you assert otherwise, then you'll have to prove it by providing the exact compiler errors.

Comment: With the correction of @utnapistim works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the problem is in the class where I overload the operator = I don't know how to copy the right object data into the left object data, I'm not sure also if I delete correctly...

You do not (delete correctly).

Operator = should alter the values of `*this`. Instead, you delete w.m1 and w.m2 (where w is your parameter).

Corrected code:

```
Mat &operator=(const Mat &w){
    int *new_ptr1 = NULL;
    new_ptr1 = new int [w.rows*w.cols];
    int *new_ptr2 = NULL;
    new_ptr2 = new int [w.rows*w.cols];
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < w.rows*w.cols; i++){
        new_ptr1[i] = w.say_m1(i);
        new_ptr2[i] = w.say_m2(i);
    }
    delete[] m1; // <<< HERE
    delete[] m2; // <<< HERE
    m1 = new_ptr1;
    m2 = new_ptr2;
    rows = w.rows;
    cols = w.cols;
    return *this;
}
```

That said, there's a host of other problems with your code:

**Assuming you wrote this code to learn how to manipulate dynamic arrays within a class:**

1. you're using a class that manages two different allocated resources directly. You should consider using a smart pointer on m1 and m2 (for exception safety).
2. Implement the rule of three: constructor (you already have this), copy constructor (you don't have this) and assignment operator (you already have this).
3. Add a destructor to your class.

** Assuming this is code you will use and did not write for learning arrays:**

1. [] use `std::vector`s for m1 and m2 instead. This will save you from having to implement the rule of three and destructor.
2. You use `using namespace std;` globally. Don't do that as it creates many many problems.

Edit:

Better code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Mat{
std::vector<int> life;
    std::vector<int> neighborhood;

public:

    // this is unnecessary
    // void write(unsigned r_max, unsigned c_max);  {

    Mat() : life(1), meighborhood(1) // fill each with 1 int with default value (0)
    {
    }

    Mat(unsigned r, unsigned c)
      : life(r), meighborhood(c) // fill each with r(and c) ints with default value (0)
    {
    }

    // ~Mat() became unnecessary: destructors of std::vector will deallocate fine

    Mat &operator=(const Mat &w) {
        // create replacements before doing changing any value
        // this way, if you get an exception while creating the data
        // the value in the obhect does not change
        std::vector<int> new_life(w.life);
        std::vector<int> new_neighborhood(w.neighborhood);

        life.swap(new_life);
        neighborhood.swap(new_neighborhood);
        return *this;
    }

    // use std::vector<int>::at which throws an exception if the index is invalid
    // if you are not interested in the validation of the index
    // return life[i] and neighborhood[i]
    int say_m1(unsigned i) const{ return life.at(i); }
    int say_m2(unsigned i) const{ return neighborhood.at(i); }
};
```

Comment: thank you for your advice, however I'm not very able to use `vectors` can you "convert" my code? If i'm not asking to much... I don't even know how I would write the destructor...

Comment: For example, the attributes became:
        `unsigned rows;
 unsigned cols;
 std::vector<int> life(rows*cols);
 std::vector<int> neighborhood(rows*cols);`

Comment: or `unsigned rows;
 unsigned cols;
 std::vector<int> life;
 std::vector<int> neighborhood;`

Comment: However I think that this question is helpful for those people like me that are studing... who is the magnificent man who voted down this post?